# Push Process Builder flow to Production with Change Set

Tags: process-builder, change-set

Is it possible to push a process builder flow from Sandbox to Production using change sets? According to Winter15 documentation, process builder is not supported by change sets. If it is still the case, how can I migrate my flows? Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

**If you are on Summer'15 Sandbox** -

Process Builder processes can be successfully deployed from one environment to another using Change Sets. You need to select "Flow Definition" in the Component drop down when adding components.

Also: When you deploy the change set, the process needs to be "activated" if its not active post deployment.

- [[Components Available in Change Sets]](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_change_sets.htm&type=5.)
- [[Deploy Processes and Flows as Active]](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_deploy_active.htm&type=5)