# Are all Flow / Process builder 'versions' pushed in a changeset?

Tags: deployment, process-builder, administration, visual-workflow, change-set

Are all versions of a flow/ process builder pushed through in a changeset?

[image]

I have over 30 versions and I only want the latest, Active one...

**Do I have to save it as a new flow and use that in the changeset?**

I cannot find any documentation to see how it works when there are lots of versions in a flow / Process builder

Comment: I think it deploys latest version which is active. Post deployment you need to activate it manually. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also refer this answer [Push Process Builder flow to Production with Change Set](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88313/push-process-builder-flow-to-production-with-change-set)

Comment: @RohitMourya - yes it will take the latest active version, so if there are any newer versions that haven't been activated they don't get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Only the ACTIVE version is pushed. Hope this helps! :)

Please review the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_distribute_changeset.htm&type=5

Comment: additional comment: it only takes the Active version upon first addition of that Flow to the change set. If you later on clone the change set, it will keep referring to that original version of the Flow and not refresh with the newest active version.